# How to use regular expression for directory paths in proftpd

Tags: regex, linux, ftp

I have some directories on my site I want to be accessible by anonymous ftp users but that they shouldn't be visible. So I don't want them to show up when typing "ls" or "dir" but I want the users to be able to type "cd secret_dir".

I was hoping this would do

```
ServerName              "ProFTPD Default Installation"
ServerType              standalone
DefaultServer           on
Port                21
Umask               022
MaxInstances            30

# Set the user and group under which the server will run.
User                nobody
Group               nogroup

RequireValidShell           off

# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
<Directory />
  AllowOverwrite            on
</Directory>

<Anonymous /home/ftp/my.site.org>
  User              ftp
  Group             planonline

  UserAlias             anonymous ftp
  MaxClients            10

  DisplayLogin          welcome.msg
  DisplayChdir          .message

  # So users can't do ls in the directory
  <Limit ALL>
    DenyAll
  </Limit>

  # All have access to this directory, for testing permissions
  <Directory "/home/ftp/my.site.org/uuid-files/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
  <Limit ALL>
    AllowAll
  </Limit>
  </Directory>

  # I want this to work but it doesn't
  <Directory "/home/ftp/my.site.org/uuid-files/[0-9a-f]">
    <Limit ALL>
      AllowAll
    </Limit>
  </Directory>
</Anonymous>
```

The user ftp and the group planonline owns the files. I can't change any of those permissions since they will be set like that by another application which create the directories. The permissions for the directories look like this:

```
sskanberg@ubuntu-develop:/home/ftp$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxr--r-- 1 ftp planonline    4 2011-11-14 13:15 ftpdir.txt
drwxrwxr-- 3 ftp planonline 4096 2011-11-14 13:08 my.site.org
```

So my question is: how can I use regular expressions in my Directory tag? Or, how can I achieve my wish in other ways: making directories invisible for ftp users but still be able to cd'ing in to them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `HideFiles`? i would guess it should be used like this:

```
<Directory "/home/ftp/my.site.org/uuid-files">
  HideFiles ^[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}$
  <Limit ALL>
    AllowAll
    IgnoreHidden on
  </Limit>
</Directory>
```